# Flow map from aggregate data with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, flow-map, movement-data

I want to create a flow map in QGIS.

I have a list of cities and I have to show how many people travel from one city to another. For example, 5 people traveled from Vantaa to Helsinki, 10 people traveled from Tampere to Helsinki, 50 people traveled from Joensuu to Helsinki etc,.
The flow strength (number of people) should be shown with different thickness lines, where 5 is the thinnest and 50 is the fattest.

Comment: It isn't clear whether you want to visualize exact ROUTES that were used or just a general migration flows from one city to another.

Comment: i would like to show  general migration flows

Comment: What spatial data are you currently working with? Do you have each city as a point? Or just your movement data in table format? The simplest solution would involve creating line features between point features representing cities (using plug-ins such as https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/PointConnector/ amongst others), with number of people attributed to the relevant line feature. With this in place you can categorically symbolise your data with line thickness dependent on your 'number of people' attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it myself so far, but i think that the Flow Mapper Plugin would be the way to go.

If you can't find the plugin, try checking "show all plugins, even those marked as experimental" under the Plugins -> Fetch python plugins -> Tab:Options

To get additional info on the plugin, browse to your .qgis folder within your users folder.

**`.qgis/python/plugins/FlowMapper`**

There you will find a folder containing a documentation (also available [here](http://www.cempro.tk/release_notes_v0.2.pdf)) and another folder with example data.

The developer rates his plugin as experimental at the moment, but fully functional.

Good luck

Comment: FlowMapper is available through the official repo, no need to add a different repo.

Comment: strange... couldn't find it, using master on Linux. Ok, will adopt my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but flow mapper didn`t solve my problem or  if i be honest it didn`t work or i just couldn`t know how to use it properly. I  went  the easy way and solved my problem by adding a new  shapefile layer (line), and then i just connected manually one city to another and typed the values what i needed and added them to the map.

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of qgis flowmapper plugin. I would be please to answer any questions regarding the plugin.

A readme and tutorial data is already included within the zip file that you have downloaded either from the plugin repo or from the website www.cempro.tk

Briefly, **supply (i) input node coordinates as text file and (ii) flow data matrix as text file  in white space deliminated format and plugin generates node2node straight flow lines automatically in shapefile format.**

**Example:** You have 3 nodes, cities a, b and c  
(i) Input node coordinates (geographic) text file should appear as;  
    30.123 42.345  
    29.345 41.456  
    29.679 40.789

(ii) Flow matrix (from city to city) text file should appear as;  
    0 100 200  
    150 0 350  
    70 140 0

**Flow mapper is tested to be working in Windows only.** It would probably cause error in MacOS or Linux due to slashes in the file paths. But if you are on Windows, you will not face any problems.